# Why postgres query is taking so long

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

I have a problematic query on a view which is taking more than 5 mins to run in aws rds production.
The query is simple and there are only 85000 records. Not able to understand why it is taking so long. If I run the query from postgres client it takes 300ms, but the same query when its running from application, in New Relic it shows 5 mins or more.
The query is :

```
select
    esnpartvie0_.esn_id as col_0_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.esn as col_1_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.quarter_point as col_2_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.work_order_number as col_3_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.site as col_4_0_,
    sum(esnpartvie0_.critical) as col_5_0_,
    sum(esnpartvie0_.numshort) as col_6_0_,
    sum(esnpartvie0_.wa) as col_7_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.customer as col_8_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.adj_accum_date as col_9_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.g2_otr as col_10_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.induct_date as col_11_0_,
    min(esnpartvie0_.delta) as col_12_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.fiscal_week_bucket_date as col_13_0_
from
    moa.esn_part_view esnpartvie0_
where
    esnpartvie0_.site_id =8
    and esnpartvie0_.esn_id =1234
group by
    esnpartvie0_.esn_id ,
    esnpartvie0_.esn ,
    esnpartvie0_.quarter_point ,
    esnpartvie0_.work_order_number ,
    esnpartvie0_.site ,
    esnpartvie0_.customer ,
    esnpartvie0_.adj_accum_date ,
    esnpartvie0_.g2_otr ,
    esnpartvie0_.induct_date ,
    esnpartvie0_.fiscal_week_bucket_date
```

---

I also have the EXPLAIN ANALYZE BUFFERS FORMAT TEXT plan from pgadmin4 ...though couldnt understand much of it

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=68482.59..68482.64 rows=1 width=82) (actual time=663.095..663.171 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: esnpartvie0_.esn_id, esnpartvie0_.esn, esnpartvie0_.quarter_point, esnpartvie0_.work_order_number, esnpartvie0_.site, esnpartvie0_.customer, esnpartvie0_.adj_accum_date, esnpartvie0_.g2_otr, esnpartvie0_.induct_date, esnpartvie0_.fiscal_week_bucket_date"
"  Buffers: shared hit=19908, temp read=27667 written=6782"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=68482.59..68482.60 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=663.087..663.163 rows=8 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: esnpartvie0_.esn, esnpartvie0_.quarter_point, esnpartvie0_.work_order_number, esnpartvie0_.site, esnpartvie0_.customer, esnpartvie0_.adj_accum_date, esnpartvie0_.g2_otr, esnpartvie0_.induct_date, esnpartvie0_.fiscal_week_bucket_date"
"        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=19908, temp read=27667 written=6782"
"        ->  Subquery Scan on esnpartvie0_  (cost=68482.49..68482.58 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=663.024..663.110 rows=8 loops=1)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=19897, temp read=27667 written=6782"
"              ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=68482.49..68482.57 rows=1 width=2016) (actual time=663.023..663.107 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                    Group Key: e.esn_id, w.number, ed.adj_accum_date, (COALESCE(ed.gate_2_otr, 0)), ed.gate_0_start, ed.gate_1_stop, p.part_id, st.name, mat.name, so.name, dr.name, hpc.hpc_status_name, module.module_name, c.customer_id, m.model_id, ef.engine_family_id, s.site_id, ws.name, ic.comment"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=19897, temp read=27667 written=6782"
"                    CTE indexed_comments"
"                      ->  WindowAgg  (cost=39839.28..44263.80 rows=221226 width=118) (actual time=165.462..272.574 rows=215274 loops=1)"
"                            Buffers: shared hit=5135, temp read=3293 written=3301"
"                            ->  Sort  (cost=39839.28..40392.34 rows=221226 width=110) (actual time=165.454..197.793 rows=215274 loops=1)"
"                                  Sort Key: part_comment.part_id, part_comment.created_at DESC"
"                                  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 26344kB"
"                                  Buffers: shared hit=5135, temp read=3293 written=3301"
"                                  ->  Seq Scan on part_comment  (cost=0.00..7344.26 rows=221226 width=110) (actual time=0.019..35.400 rows=215274 loops=1)"
"                                        Buffers: shared hit=5132"
"                    ->  Sort  (cost=24218.69..24218.70 rows=1 width=717) (actual time=663.017..663.090 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                          Sort Key: w.number, ed.adj_accum_date, (COALESCE(ed.gate_2_otr, 0)), ed.gate_0_start, ed.gate_1_stop, p.part_id, st.name, mat.name, so.name, dr.name, hpc.hpc_status_name, module.module_name, c.customer_id, m.model_id, ef.engine_family_id, s.site_id, ws.name, ic.comment"
"                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=19897, temp read=27667 written=6782"
"                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1010.23..24218.68 rows=1 width=717) (actual time=412.426..663.017 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=19894, temp read=27667 written=6782"
"                                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.94..24210.36 rows=1 width=697) (actual time=412.389..662.811 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                      Join Filter: (ic.part_id = p.part_id)"
"                                      Rows Removed by Join Filter: 467615"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=19870, temp read=27667 written=6782"
"                                      ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.94..19218.95 rows=1 width=181) (actual time=56.592..57.839 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=14735"
"                                            ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.81..19218.35 rows=1 width=183) (actual time=56.583..57.812 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=14735"
"                                                  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.67..19217.66 rows=1 width=181) (actual time=56.576..57.790 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=14735"
"                                                        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.55..19216.82 rows=1 width=179) (actual time=56.567..57.759 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=14735"
"                                                              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.42..19216.04 rows=1 width=178) (actual time=56.552..57.699 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=14719"
"                                                                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.28..19215.37 rows=1 width=175) (actual time=56.536..57.638 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=14703"
"                                                                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.14..19214.77 rows=1 width=170) (actual time=56.514..57.556 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                                                                Join Filter: (e.work_scope_id = ws.work_scope_id)"
"                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=14687"
"                                                                                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.14..19213.54 rows=1 width=166) (actual time=56.487..57.481 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                                                                      Join Filter: (e.esn_id = p.esn_id)"
"                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=14679"
"                                                                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=9.14..31.40 rows=1 width=125) (actual time=0.084..0.134 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                            Buffers: shared hit=15"
"                                                                                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.87..23.08 rows=1 width=118) (actual time=0.072..0.122 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=12"
"                                                                                                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.73..21.86 rows=1 width=108) (actual time=0.063..0.111 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                        Buffers: shared hit=10"
"                                                                                                        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.60..21.65 rows=1 width=46) (actual time=0.052..0.100 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                              Buffers: shared hit=8"
"                                                                                                              ->  Hash Join  (cost=8.31..13.34 rows=1 width=41) (actual time=0.043..0.089 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                                    Hash Cond: (m.model_id = e.model_id)"
"                                                                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=5"
"                                                                                                                    ->  Seq Scan on model m  (cost=0.00..4.39 rows=239 width=17) (actual time=0.011..0.039 rows=240 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                                                                                                    ->  Hash  (cost=8.30..8.30 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                                                                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                                                                                                          ->  Index Scan using esn_pkey on esn e  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                                                Index Cond: (esn_id = 140339)"
"                                                                                                                                Filter: active"
"                                                                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                                                                                              ->  Index Scan using work_order_pkey on work_order w  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=13) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                                    Index Cond: (work_order_id = e.work_order_id)"
"                                                                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                                                                                        ->  Index Scan using engine_family_pkey on engine_family ef  (cost=0.14..0.20 rows=1 width=66) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                              Index Cond: (engine_family_id = m.engine_family_id)"
"                                                                                                              Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                                                                                  ->  Index Scan using site_pkey on site s  (cost=0.14..1.15 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                        Index Cond: (site_id = ef.site_id)"
"                                                                                                        Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                                                                            ->  Index Scan using customer_pkey on customer c  (cost=0.27..8.29 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                  Index Cond: (customer_id = e.customer_id)"
"                                                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                                                                      ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..19181.78 rows=29 width=41) (actual time=56.400..57.333 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                                                                            Workers Planned: 2"
"                                                                                            Workers Launched: 2"
"                                                                                            Buffers: shared hit=14664"
"                                                                                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on part p  (cost=0.00..18178.88 rows=12 width=41) (actual time=51.721..52.608 rows=3 loops=3)"
"                                                                                                  Filter: (active AND (esn_id = 140339))"
"                                                                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 224748"
"                                                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=14664"
"                                                                                ->  Seq Scan on work_scope ws  (cost=0.00..1.10 rows=10 width=12) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=8)"
"                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=8"
"                                                                          ->  Index Scan using source_pkey on source so  (cost=0.14..0.57 rows=1 width=13) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=8)"
"                                                                                Index Cond: (p.source_id = source_id)"
"                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=16"
"                                                                    ->  Index Scan using status_pkey on status st  (cost=0.13..0.56 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=8)"
"                                                                          Index Cond: (p.status_id = status_id)"
"                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=16"
"                                                              ->  Index Scan using material_stream_pkey on material_stream mat  (cost=0.13..0.56 rows=1 width=9) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=8)"
"                                                                    Index Cond: (p.material_stream_id = material_stream_id)"
"                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=16"
"                                                        ->  Index Scan using dr_status_pkey on dr_status dr  (cost=0.13..0.56 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=8)"
"                                                              Index Cond: (p.dr_status_id = dr_status_id)"
"                                                  ->  Index Scan using hpc_status_pkey on hpc_status hpc  (cost=0.13..0.56 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=8)"
"                                                        Index Cond: (p.hpc_status_id = hpc_status_id)"
"                                            ->  Index Scan using module_pkey on module  (cost=0.14..0.57 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=8)"
"                                                  Index Cond: (p.module_id = module_id)"
"                                      ->  CTE Scan on indexed_comments ic  (cost=0.00..4977.59 rows=1106 width=520) (actual time=20.687..71.973 rows=58452 loops=8)"
"                                            Filter: (comment_index = 1)"
"                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 156822"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=5135, temp read=27667 written=6782"
"                                ->  Index Scan using esn_dates_esn_id_key on esn_dates ed  (cost=0.29..8.32 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.020..0.021 rows=1 loops=8)"
"                                      Index Cond: (esn_id = 140339)"
"                                      Filter: ((gate_3_stop_actual AND (gate_3_stop >= now())) OR (gate_3_stop IS NULL) OR ((NOT gate_3_stop_actual) AND (gate_3_stop IS NOT NULL) AND (gate_3_stop >= (now() - '730 days'::interval))))"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=24"
"Planning time: 6.580 ms"
"Execution time: 673.922 ms"
```

---

The view definition (moa.esn_part_view) on which the above query is selecting

```
with indexed_comments as (
select
    part_comment.part_id,
    part_comment.comment,
    row_number() over (partition by part_comment.part_id
order by
    part_comment.created_at desc) as comment_index
from
    moa.part_comment
        )
 select
    e.esn_id,
    e.name as esn,
    e.is_qp_engine as quarter_point,
    w.number as work_order_number,
    case
        when (p.part_id is null) then 0
        else p.part_id
    end as part_id,
    p.part_number,
    p.part_description,
    p.quantity,
    st.name as status,
    p.status_id,
    mat.name as material_stream,
    p.material_stream_id,
    so.name as source,
    p.source_id,
    p.oem,
    p.po_number,
    p.manual_cso_commit,
    p.auto_cso_commit,
    coalesce(p.manual_cso_commit, p.auto_cso_commit) as calculated_cso_commit,
    (coalesce(ed.adj_accum_date, (ed.gate_1_stop + coalesce(ed.gate_2_otr, 0)), ed.gate_0_start) + p.accum_offset) as adjusted_accum,
    dr.name as dr_status,
    p.dr_status_id,
    p.airway_bill,
    p.core_material,
    hpc.hpc_status_name as hpc_status,
    p.hpc_status_id,
    module.module_name,
    p.module_id,
    c.name as customer,
    c.customer_id,
    m.name as model,
    m.model_id,
    ef.name as engine_family,
    ef.engine_family_id,
    s.label as site,
    s.site_id,
    case
        when (coalesce(p.manual_cso_commit, p.auto_cso_commit) > coalesce(ed.adj_accum_date, (ed.gate_1_stop + coalesce(ed.gate_2_otr, 0)), ed.gate_0_start)) then 1
        else 0
    end as critical,
    case
        when (coalesce(p.manual_cso_commit, p.auto_cso_commit) <= coalesce(ed.adj_accum_date, (ed.gate_1_stop + coalesce(ed.gate_2_otr, 0)), ed.gate_0_start)) then 1
        else 0
    end as numshort,
    case
        when ((p.esn_id is not null)
        and (coalesce(p.manual_cso_commit, p.auto_cso_commit) is null)) then 1
        else 0
    end as wa,
    ed.adj_accum_date,
    (ed.gate_1_stop + coalesce(ed.gate_2_otr, 0)) as g2_otr,
    ed.gate_0_start as induct_date,
    coalesce((coalesce(ed.adj_accum_date, (ed.gate_1_stop + coalesce(ed.gate_2_otr, 0))) - max(coalesce(p.manual_cso_commit, p.auto_cso_commit))), 0) as delta,
    coalesce(ed.adj_accum_date, (ed.gate_1_stop + coalesce(ed.gate_2_otr, 0)), ed.gate_0_start) as fiscal_week_bucket_date,
    p.po_line_num,
    p.ship_out,
    p.receipt,
    p.crit_ship,
    e.work_scope_id,
    ws.name as work_scope,
    p.late_call,
    p.ex_esn,
    p.accum_offset,
    ic.comment as latest_comment
from
    (((((((((((((((moa.esn e
join moa.work_order w
        using (work_order_id))
join moa.model m
        using (model_id))
join moa.engine_family ef on
    ((m.engine_family_id = ef.engine_family_id)))
join moa.site s on
    ((ef.site_id = s.site_id)))
join moa.customer c
        using (customer_id))
left join moa.part p on
    (((e.esn_id = p.esn_id)
        and (p.active <> false))))
left join moa.work_scope ws on
    ((e.work_scope_id = ws.work_scope_id)))
left join moa.source so on
    ((p.source_id = so.source_id)))
left join moa.status st on
    ((p.status_id = st.status_id)))
left join moa.material_stream mat
        using (material_stream_id))
left join moa.dr_status dr
        using (dr_status_id))
left join moa.hpc_status hpc
        using (hpc_status_id))
left join moa.module module
        using (module_id))
left join indexed_comments ic on
    (((ic.part_id = p.part_id)
        and (ic.comment_index = 1))))
join moa.esn_dates ed on
    ((e.esn_id = ed.esn_id)))
where
    ((e.active = true)
        and (((ed.gate_3_stop_actual = true)
            and (ed.gate_3_stop >= now()))
            or (ed.gate_3_stop is null)
                or ((ed.gate_3_stop_actual = false)
                    and (ed.gate_3_stop is not null)
                        and (ed.gate_3_stop >= (now() - '730 days'::interval)))))
group by
    e.esn_id,
    w.number,
    s.label,
    c.name,
    p.active,
    ed.adj_accum_date,
    coalesce(ed.gate_2_otr, 0),
    ed.gate_0_start,
    ed.gate_1_stop,
    p.part_id,
    st.name,
    mat.name,
    so.name,
    dr.name,
    hpc.hpc_status_name,
    module.module_name,
    c.customer_id,
    m.name,
    m.model_id,
    ef.name,
    ef.engine_family_id,
    s.site_id,
    ws.name,
    ic.comment;
```

Comment: Please consider instructions for `[postgresql-performance]` questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info, and edit accordingly.

Comment: The JSON output of the EXPLAIN statement is not really meant for humans. Please generated the execution plan using `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)` and then add that to your question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I Have edited the post with EXPLAIN ANALYZE sql statemennt

Answer (score 1):

It looks so this query returns 200K of rows. Some clients are very slow when they have to read lot of rows from server. Some times can be slow network communication.

Comment: do u mean to say if we increase the CPU of the client..it will give some relief to the client

Comment: maybe, maybe not - it depends when is real bottle neck. From execution plan, the query returns just one row - so it should be fast everywhere - so problems are probably elsewhere than in database, maybe there are network issues. This query is not simple, from plan you can see, so this is view with CTE and window agg, so maybe another performance problem can be in view definition. CTE and window functions can stop some optimizations.

Comment: I have given the View definition of the above query...if you have any suggestions for optimizations

Comment: any inputs from your side on the View definition

Comment: There is nothing special - maybe there are more multi attribute joins - there is ` Rows Removed by Join Filter: 467615"` High number in rows removed by join filter is signal so probably need composite indexes somewhere. Possible problem can be in CTE scan, that does lot of writes to temp files. It can be slow. The speed of writing to temp files can be very different on different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

> If I run the query from postgres client it takes 300ms

So your query is not slow, your client (application code) is.

Few things to consider here:

- does the client actually need thousands of rows at once? if this is for example user-facing UI, you probably want some pages, and you can limit what you get from DB to one page at the time
- does client "buffer" the results (storing them in some kind of list/dictionary), or does your code do any processing in streaming manner (as it gets rows from DB reader). Time to transfer results to client counts into "total query time", and if your client is slow to accept rows from reader, that is your reason.